# Could not load com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl

Tags: java

I have written a Class to pre-compile the XSL stylesheets and load them into the application. This class runs in a thread. But I am getting the following error while starting tomcat.

```
Jul 16, 2016 11:21:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:109)
    at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:144)
    at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:231)
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:101)
    at CCBeans.CompileStylesheet$PollThread.run(CompileStylesheet.java:187)
```

Here I am also attaching the code snippet

```
public void run() {
    while (DEVELOPMENT) {
        try {

            String str1 = "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory";
            String str2 = "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl";
            java.util.Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.put(str2, str2);
            System.setProperties(properties);

            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            // TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
            File lFileXSLDirectory = new File(iFileXSLDirectoryPath);

            if (lFileXSLDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                String[] lFileListArray = lFileXSLDirectory.list();
                int lFileListCount = lFileListArray.length;

                for (int i = 0; i < lFileListCount; i++) {
                    if (lFileListArray[i].endsWith(".xsl")) {
                        File lFileXSL = new File(iFileXSLDirectoryPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i]);

                        if (iHashStyleTimestamp.get(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i]) == null) {
                            Templates templates = tFactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i]));
                            iHashStyleObject.put(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i], templates);
                            iHashStyleTimestamp.put(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i], new Long(lFileXSL.lastModified()));
                        } else {
                            long fileLastModifiedTime = ((Long) iHashStyleTimestamp.get(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i])).longValue();

                            if (lFileXSL.lastModified() > fileLastModifiedTime) {
                                Templates templates = tFactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i]));
                                iHashStyleObject.put(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i], templates);
                                iHashStyleTimestamp.put(iFileXSLHttpPath + "/" + lFileListArray[i], new Long(lFileXSL.lastModified()));
                                System.out.println("Refreshing File :: " + lFileListArray[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sleep(new Long(Utility.PropVal.getPropVal("WSC.XSLDirectoryRefreshTime")).longValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why specify the default Transformer Factory. just use it.

Comment: Does this anything related to "SEVERE: The web application [/PreActivation] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2] but has failed to stop it."


Jul 17, 2016 12:53:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/PreActivation] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 17, 2016 12:53:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/PreActivation]